# Using CHIP cluster to make a render farm?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

The $9 CHIP computer has mali 400 GPU. Can a number of this be used as a render farm? Will it be a cost effective alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: If you can get Blender to compile on it, you *might* be able to get CPU rendering. GPU rendering is not going to happen (the Mali 400 doesn't have a compute pipeline to support OpenCL or CUDA).

Will it be a cost effective alternative to a "real" render farm? Not likely.